# Where does nvm store node.js installations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

I can't find the location of node.js installations, downloaded and installed via e.g.:

```
nvm install 5.0
```

Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`nvm which 5.0` Will give you the path where that version of Node.js is installed

Comment: Thanks, man! (My bad, I overlooked the answer in the manual). In my case the path was `/home/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.1/bin/node`.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The `nvm root` answer should now be accepted.

Answer (score 14):

My version of nvm (1.1.7) does not have `nvm which`.  The command `nvm root` does show the "directory where nvm should store different versions of node.js".

Answer (score 1):

If using Windows nvm the NVM_HOME environment variable shows where the runtimes are located.

Run this in Powershell if you don't want to use the UI:

Get-ChildItem env: | where name -eq 'NVM_HOME'

Answer (score 0):

Another command that can be used to find where nvm installs various versions of Node.js:

```
which node
```

**Note:** It works only if your system is using a version of Node.js installed via nvm and not via some other route.